# Как найти объект и перейти по ссылке этого объекта на новый файл?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. Имею такую ситуацию, есть йс  файл, который содержит объект с числами. В html файл имею поле и кнопку поиска. Нужно, чтобы после воода числа в поле поиска и нажатия на кнопку поискa осуществлился поиск по имеющимися номерами js файла.

Любая помощь будет полезна, заранее спасибо.

P.S. После нахождения нужно автоматически перейти на страницу найденного объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ситуация, конечно, не из приятных :-) Разобраться с ней поможет чтение документации по методу [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) и интерфейсу [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```js
var obj = {
  0: 'foo',
  1: 'bar',
  2: 'baz'
};

var form = document.querySelector('#searchForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // вырубаем стандартный сабмит
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var num = data.get('num');
  if (obj[num]) {
    alert(obj[num]);
    // document.location.replace(obj[num]);
  } else {
    alert('Not found');
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="num">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Брат, смотри, это работает, но можно все это сделать так, чтобы var obj был таким: 
var obj = { H0 - number0: 'foo', H1 - number1: 'bar', H2 - number2: 'baz' };
И когда в поле поиска введут номер 0 или 1 или dva был выведен foo или bar или  baz?

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk конечно! Конкатенация -- наше всё! `var num = 'H' + data.get('num');`

Comment: Брат прямо от души в душу спасибо. Наверное не представишь, как сильно помо.